# VS 2012 express Edition, windows phone 8, database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

i have to develop a windows phone 8 application with a local database, i would like to know if we can create a local database with SQLite or SQL Server Compact Edition in vs 2012 express edition, i ve installed this version but i can not find the server explorer !!!

Comment: There was a CodeProject article on this added earlier today - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572081/SQLite-For-Windows-8-Metro-WinRt

Comment: thank you at least i use SQlite database!

Answer (score 0):

try using SQL Server Compact Toolbox